# Chrome extension transparent background and rounded corners (like Save To Pocket)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pocket

So this plugin clearly has transparent background and rounded corners:

[image]

Even when you scroll down on the page the background will scroll behind it, so it's unlikely any trick with `captureVisibleTab` is being done.

So I'm wondering how this was achieved, because any other SO-articles seem to suggest it is impossible, however they are pretty old:

- [Make Chrome Extension Popup Window Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944465/make-chrome-extension-popup-window-transparent)
- [How to make border radius in popup chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899635/how-to-make-border-radius-in-popup-chrome-extension)
- [Curved corners on a popup.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900818/curved-corners-on-a-popup-html/4901106#4901106)

I'm curious what kind of hack they have used, or that I'm missing something obvious in the docs.

For me at least simply setting `background-color: transparent;` on any element in the `popup.html` does not do anything.

Have they used a trick by loading 2 separate html files with an offset? That still doesn't explain the rounded corners though.

Comment: If you inspect it you'll see it's simply a DOM element in the current web page. Also nothing's changed as the extension API development is mostly frozen over the last 5 years.

Comment: Ahhh... I knew there was something different about it!

Answer (score 2):

As @woxxom pointed out, the 'popup' is rendered on the page itself and not in a popup.html.

You can see its offset from where a plugin would normally be shown.